# Работа с Анонимным типом в качестве DataSource для DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, linq, типы-данных

Есть некоторый анонимный тип, который был получен в результате LINQ запроса.

Я его подключил к DataGridView в качестве DataSource.

Подскажите, как я могу извлечь данные по строке, которую выбрал пользователь?

Например с именованным типом все легко:

```
var t= (<Именованный тип>)dgv.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem;
```

После этого через переменную t, я могу обращаться к полям.

Как быть с анонимными типами? Городить именованные типы ради пары обращений не хочется...

Comment: можно попробовать использовать [`dynamic`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd264741.aspx)

Comment: А как это будет выглядеть? Просто, преобразовать к dynamic?

Comment: например так: `dynamic t= dgv.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem;`

Comment: А к полям как обращаться? В таком виде VS ничего не подсвечивает.

Comment: да, не подсвечивает. к полям как обычно через точку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как всегда ответ в документации [**MSDN**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb397696.aspx#Anchor_0) машинный перевод в данном фрагменте совсем убогий, поэтому цитирую оригинал.

> You cannot declare a field, a property, an event, or the return type
>   of a method as having an anonymous type.Similarly, you cannot declare
>   a formal parameter of a method, property, constructor, or indexer as
>   having an anonymous type.To pass an anonymous type, or a collection
>   that contains anonymous types, as an argument to a method, you can
>   declare the parameter as type object.However, doing this defeats the
>   purpose of strong typing.If you must store query results or pass them
>   outside the method boundary, consider using an ordinary named struct
>   or class instead of an anonymous type.

Перевод (сильно не пинать, поправлю если найдете ошибку):

> Вы не можете использовать анонимные типы для объявления полей,
>   свойств, событий или возвращаемых значений и параметров методов. Чтобы использовать
>   анонимный тип или коллекцию содержащую анонимные типы в качестве
>   аргумента метода, вы можете объявить параметр типа object.
>   Однако,подобное решение, противоречит целям строгой типизации. Если
>   вам нужно хранить результаты запроса или передать их за пределы
>   метода, используйте обычные именованные структуры или классы вместо
>   анонимных.

Есть пара трюков позволяющих обойти это ограничение, но оба не добавляют качества коду, так что использовать или нет, думайте сами.
1. Использовать `dynamic` по совету @Grundy, в этом случае мы получаем отсутствие автокомплита для полей.
2. Второй вариант ([источник](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/gaidar/2008/10/27/1583/)):

> Перед тем как читать дальше, я прошу слабонервных и легко
>   восприимчивых к грязным трюкам закрыть глаза.
>
> … для того, чтобы возвращать анонимные типы из методов.
>
> Предположим, что у нас есть следующий метод:
>
> static object GetBeatleName() { return new { First = “John”, Last =
>   “Lennon” }; }
>
> Метод возвращает некий объект, что замечательно, однако чтобы этим
>   объектом можно было удобно пользоваться, прибегнем к описанному выше
>   методу и определим вспомогательный обобщенный метод для приведения
>   типов:
>
> static T CastType(object obj, T type) { return (T)obj; }
>
> которым воспользуемся так:
>
> var beatle = CastType(obj, new {First = “”, Last = “”});
>
> Как и в предыдущем примере мы используем технику типизации экземпляром
>   объекта. В результате можем дальше отлично работать с полученным
>   объектом:
>
> Console.WriteLine(“First = {0}, Last = {1}”, beatle.First,
>   beatle.Last);
>
> Сама по себе техника очень интересна и может быть полезна, однако,
>   перед тем как бросаться использовать эту технику для возвращения
>   анонимных типов, подумайте – если у вас есть тип, который стоит
>   повторно использовать в других методах, то почему бы не описать его
>   как подобает и не использовать лишнего шаманства, имеющего тенденцию к
>   снижению читаемости кода.

оба метода протестированы и работают, но мое мнение - не использовать никогда.

Comment: Если сразу использовать тип, то да, нету. А вот если анонимный тип привязать как набор данных, то уже появляются... Так как для того, что бы из row получить поля DataSource, нужно выполнить преобразование... Я, в принципе, погуглил и нашел решение в виде рефлексии...

Comment: @iluxa1810 как видите я специально добавил вложенный анонимный тип. с ним тоже проблем нет.

Comment: ок, попробую потестить с привязкой. к чему привязывать? для чистоты эксперимента...

Comment: Привяжи к Datagridview и попробуй получить доступ к полям элемента на который указывает юзер . Я в вопросе описал способ, которым я без проблем получаю данные с именованным типом

Comment: @iluxa1810 нашел я ответ на ваш вопрос. Можно, оба варианта так себе.

Comment: @iluxa1810 ну или совсем уж закопаться в рефлексию, но тогда уж точно проще класс отдельный создать.